# Posting to FB Page error(s)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Scenario: I want to get user access token of the fb page admin by JS login and retrieving token ONE TIME, and will store that in database. Then daily, I want to do wall post to those page.

I am using JS to get the initial token and storing it. Then using c# FacebookSDK for the web requests.

```
FB.login(function (response) {

    var r = response;

    // get access token of the user and update in database
    $("#FacebookAccessToken").val(response.authResponse.accessToken);

},
{
    scope: 'manage_pages,publish_stream'
});
```

Now I am saving this token in database as I will be using this for future graph calls - **is this right**?

On server side when I need to do a post after a day I retrieve that token and do the processing as below:

```
// step 1 get application access token
var fb1 = new FacebookClient();
dynamic appTokenCLient = fb1.Get("oauth/access_token", new
{
    client_id = appId,
    client_secret = appSecret,
    grant_type = "client_credentials",
    scope = "manage_pages,publish_stream",
    redirect_uri = siteUrl
});

var fbTokenSettingVal = GetTokenFromDB(); // getting access token from database which was stored during JS fb login

// step 2 extend token
var fb2 = new FacebookClient(appTokenCLient.access_token);
dynamic extendedToken = fb2.Get("oauth/access_token", new
{
    client_id = appId,
    client_secret = appSecret,
    grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
    fb_exchange_token = fbTokenSettingVal.Val
});

var userExtendedToken = extendedToken.access_token; // get extended token and update database

// step 3 get page access token from the pages, that the user manages
var fb3 = new FacebookClient { AppId = appId, AppSecret = appSecret, AccessToken = userExtendedToken };
var fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var publishedResponse = fb3.Get("/me/accounts", fbParams) as JsonObject;
var data = JArray.Parse(publishedResponse["data"].ToString());

var pageToken = "";
foreach (var account in data)
{
    if (account["name"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("PAGE_NAME"))
    {
        pageToken = account["access_token"].ToString();
        break;
    }
}


// step 4 post a link to the page - throws error !
var fb4 = new FacebookClient(pageToken);

fb4.Post("/PAGE_NAME/feed",
    new
    {
        link = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    });
```

The last 4th step throws error, when posting to selected page:
**The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**

Have tried several different ways, but in vain. Assume that there is just a simple step which I am doing wrong here.

Also, is it ok to extend the fb access token for user every time before making request?
Any way to check if token is expired or not?

Comment: does it work for yourself? I mean, if you (the app developer) go through the whole login process and try to post on one of you fan pages via app, does it work? If not, there's a problem with the authentication flow. By the way, I see this publish_stream a lot. Mine works properly with `publish_actions`, though. Not sure if it's that.

Comment: Is it this issue from the top of the bug tracker? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/754785807919193/ - that applies to unpublished posts

Comment: Thanks for responses, got the reason, see my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that access token for future. You need to take offline_access token and that token you need to store in database.

This offline accesstoken will be expire once user will change the password or delete your application from facebook account.

```
 private void GetPermenentAccessTokenOfUser(string accessToken)
    {
        var client2 = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        //get permenent access token
        dynamic result = client2.Post("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = _apiKey,
            client_secret = _apiSecret,
            grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
            fb_exchange_token = accessToken
        });
        _accessToken = result.access_token;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, offline_access is deprecated; source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for new apps we need to apply for `manage_pages` permission from our application:

[image]

which I am doing now. As it shows error when doing login:

[image]

Also, the app needs to be live, so they can reproduce this permission and verify that we do need this permission to post to pages. Its good for fb users safety but a time taking process for developers.

**Any way this can be skipped for testing purpose?**